# CentOS partitioning

Tags: centos

I have a CentOS server with two 1 TB disks. However, it is badly partitioned.
Please check below:

```
[root@p16282558 ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd4f28eb2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1         523     4194304   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdb2             523         784     2097152   82  Linux swap / Solaris
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdb3             784      121602   970470104   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 3 does not end on cylinder boundary.

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x724abfe3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1         523     4194304   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2             523         784     2097152   82  Linux swap / Solaris
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda3             784      121602   970470104   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 3 does not end on cylinder boundary.

Disk /dev/md3: 993.8 GB, 993761296384 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 242617504 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/md1: 4294 MB, 4294901760 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 1048560 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-usr: 4294 MB, 4294967296 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 522 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-var: 4294 MB, 4294967296 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 522 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-home: 4294 MB, 4294967296 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 522 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

When I ran the DF command:

```
[root@p16282558 ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1              4.0G  4.0G     0 100% /
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr  4.0G  1.5G  2.4G  38% /usr
/dev/mapper/vg00-var  4.0G  880M  2.9G  23% /var
/dev/mapper/vg00-home
                      4.0G  136M  3.7G   4% /home
none                  7.9G  556K  7.9G   1% /tmp
```

/opt is within /, and no space left in /

When i ran, /etc/fstab

```
/dev/md1        /               ext3    defaults        1 1
/dev/sda2   none            swap    sw
/dev/sdb2   none            swap    sw
/dev/vg00/usr   /usr            ext4    defaults        0 2
/dev/vg00/var   /var            ext4    defaults,usrquota   0 2
/dev/vg00/home  /home           ext4    defaults,usrquota   0 2
devpts          /dev/pts        devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
none            /proc           proc    defaults        0 0
none            /tmp    tmpfs   defaults        0 0
```

So there is a full md1 disk, and a non-utilised Disk /dev/md3 with 993.8 GB free??

But,

```
[root@p16282558 ~]# df -h /dev/md3
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
-                     7.9G  204K  7.9G   1% /dev
```

Results of PVS and LVS.

```
[root@p16282558 ~]# pvs
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/md3   vg00 lvm2 a--  925.51g 913.51g

[root@p16282558 ~]# lvs
  LV   VG   Attr      LSize Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  home vg00 -wi-ao--- 4.00g
  usr  vg00 -wi-ao--- 4.00g
  var  vg00 -wi-ao--- 4.00g
```

Does this mean /dev is not being mounted at system start (as per fstab)  ?

My problem is: /opt and /var should be mounted in a disk/partition with more space.
How can i restructure the disk to utilize all disk space in an efficient way?

Please help.

Thanks,
Sash

Comment: Can you add the outputs of `pvs` and `lvs` into your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are using LVM on /dev/md3 and that you have only allocated 12GB out of the 1TB available there.

If /opt is where you are spending most of the capacity, you can create a new logical volume and call it vg00-opt. Once that has been created, you can mount it temporarily on /mnt/whatever and move the files from /opt into the new logical volume. Finally you can mount vg00-opt on /opt.

The `df -h /dev/md3` command that you typed only told you how much space is used and available on the filesystem used for /dev. Both /tmp and /dev are using tmpfs which will use RAM and/or swap to store the files. Those directories will be empty at boot, but entries in /dev are automatically generated by a deamon started at boot. By default the capacity of a tmpfs is half the amount of RAM, so those two are 8GB in size because you have 16GB of RAM.

Comment: Hi, i have done the following: # create a new 5gb logical volume
lvcreate -n opt -L 5G vg00

# format it as ext4
mkfs.ext4 /dev/vg00/opt

# move the old dir out of the way
mv /opt /opt.orig

# mount the new logical volume
echo "/dev/vg00/opt /opt ext4 defaults 0 2" >> /etc/fstab
mkdir /opt
mount /opt

# move all data into the new mount
mv /opt.orig/* /opt
rmdir /opt.orig

Comment: But after these steps when i ran df -h it doesn't show /dev/mapper/vg00-opt???

Comment: My best guess is that /etc/mtab is not completely up to date with actual mounts. It is possible that the disk was so full, there wasn't free space enough to update /etc/mtab.

If you have freed up some space, you can try to umount /opt and then mount it again.